# problema deploy ionic en vercel

Tags: ionic, vercel

mi aplicacion ionic alojada en vercel compila pero no funciona, cuando entro al link generado me muestra una pagina en blanco y solo me carga el icon del la url mi archivo vercel.json es:

```
    {
  "version": 2,
  "name": "proyecto",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "/package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "outputDirectory": "dist/repo"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.\.(css|js|jpg|png|svg|ico|woff|woff2))$",
      "dest": "/dist/repo/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(assets/.)",
      "dest": "/dist/repo/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/.*",
      "dest": "/dist/repo/www/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```